# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error jsp-tomcat database

Tags: database, jsp

I am new to database and cannot find a way to handle this error. I am trying to make connection between my jsp file and sql server using eclipse. I copied my ms sql driver into WEB-INF/lib and configured "Build path" so it points to this driver but it gives error.  What is my mistake, and how can I correct it ?

> Here the Error Message:

```
Message java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrap per.java:572)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:48 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.Datab_jsp$Actor.getActors(Datab_jsp.java:54)
org.apache.jsp.Datab_jsp._jspService(Datab_jsp.java:193)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:44
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

My Code in jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import=" javax.sql.DataSource" %>

<% Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>


<%! 
    public class Actor {

        String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/demo"; 

        String username = "root";
        String password = "7170256aziz";

        Connection connection  = null;
        PreparedStatement selectActors = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null; 


        public Actor(){


            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password); 

                selectActors = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT name, id, address FROM demo"); 

            } catch(SQLException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

            public ResultSet getActors(){

                try{

                    resultSet = selectActors.executeQuery();


                } catch (SQLException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return resultSet;   
            }

    }
%>
<%
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    ResultSet actors =  actor.getActors();
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. What I did was:

1. Changed the driver 6.4 to 4.0
2. Changed URL syntax to "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=demo;integratedSecurity=true;"
3. Changed "SELECT name, id, address FROM demo" to "SELECT name, id, address FROM people", where people is my table name
4. Copied sqljdbc_auth.dll to Windows/system32

Thereafter error messages gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` in `Actor()`

```
public Actor(){
      try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password); 
         selectActors = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT name, id, address FROM demo"); 
         } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

Comment: It gives "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException" error.

Comment: @A.Aziz you need import sqlserver jdbc jar to your project